# $\binom{3n}{n} \equiv 1 \mod 6n+1$ implies $6n+1$ is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\binom{3n}{n} \equiv 1 \mod 6n+1$ for $n>0,$ prove that $6n+1$ is composite.

Since $n>0,$ it suffices to assume that $6n+1$ is prime, and then show that $3n(3n-1)\cdots(2n+1) \equiv n(n-1)\cdots1 \mod 6n+1$ leads to a contradiction.

My idea is to use the fact that $6n+1$ is assumed to be prime to multiply by inverses until we reach a contradiction like $1 \equiv 2.$ We have $(2n+i)^{-1} = 3(6n+3i)^{-1} = 3(3i-1)^{-1}$ and $(n-i)^{-1} = 6(6n-6i)^{-1} = -6(1+6i)^{-1},$ which doesn't seem to help much. Here is what happens for $n=3$ as an example:

Assume $9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \equiv 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \mod 19.$

Multiply by $9^{-1} = -2$ and cancel to get $8 \cdot 7 \equiv -3.$ From here, we notice that $8^{-1} = -7,$ so $8 = -7^{-1}$ and we get $-1 \equiv -3,$ contradiction.

For $n=5,$ we must disprove $15 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \equiv 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \mod 31.$ Note that $15^{-1} = -2$ and $14 = (-11)^{-1},$ so we just need to disprove $13 \cdot 12 \equiv 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3.$ But $12 = 4 \cdot 3,$ so we have $13 \equiv 5 \mod 31,$ which is clearly false.

How does this approach generalize?

Comment: Well, [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%7Bn%2CMod%5BBinomial%5B3*n%2C+n%5D%2C6*n%2B1%5D%7D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D) says that $\binom{3n}{n}\not\equiv 1 \bmod 6n+1$ is never true for $n\le 100$.

Comment: @lhf "$\not\equiv \dots$ never true"? Is that an intentional double negative? In any case, the congruence holds for $n=9.$

Comment: Sorry, delete "never". For $n=9$, I get $\binom{27}{9}= 4686825 \equiv 0 \bmod 55$.